# Is it possible to generate/produce a c0000005 Access Violation Exception in pure managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, managed

I live in the belief that is not possible to produce / generate an Access Violation Exception in "pure" managed code in .Net. If one looks at .Net as flawless and does not use any external libraries (that is not managed) through for example interop.

Am I living in a fantasy?

Comment: Actually .NET uses Win API, so this exception is still possible, just a bit harder to induce.

Comment: _If one looks at .Net as flawless_ ... You can write bad code in any language or framework.

Answer (score 5):

```
throw new AccessViolationException();
```

This is pure managed code and it produces AccessViolationException :P

Comment: That's a smart and correct answer, and I'm aware of that :) Maybe I need to clarify my question. What I mean with an Access Violation is an the error from the operating system, telling the program that it is  reading or writing for example an invalid memory address.

Comment: Heheheh it's just a joke. Other than this way, it's diffult to produce but not impossible.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the following code (it only throws AccessViolationException because of malformed input though):

```
IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(123);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(123, ptr, true);
```

Comment: This piece of code will produce **Corrupted State Exception**, which cannot be caught in try-catch block (int .NET4+) without additional tricks. This is more natural behaviour than just throwing `new AccessViolationException();`

Answer (score 4):

You can e.g. use WPF which does call into your graphics card driver. You can easily get AcessViolationExceptions pre .NET 4.5 those with a buggy graphics card drivers which are not at all uncommon.

In a strange sense you are right. With .NET 4.5 and above you will never get AccessViolationExceptions in managed code anymore because the .NET runtime does not convert an AccessViolation coming from unmanaged code to an AccessViolationException anymore but it does terminate your process immediately. I guess MS support was tired to search for .NET Framework bugs only to find that it was a buggy graphics card driver.

Answer (score 2):

You almost never see the CPU actually throw one asynchronously (in the middle of something) because the .NET just-in-time compiler usually provokes an exception if 'this' is null in a method call. It puts `cmp [rcx],rcx` at the call site to provoke an exception before it potentially uses 0 as the address. It is possible to have large enough field offsets to read readable memory with a null pointer, so this guards against that.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/16/4407029.aspx

There is no magic, C# becomes instructions just like any other compiled language. There is no reason to feel all cozy about how AV's will never happen.

Comment: The mentioned assembler instruction is a null check created for a callvirt IL instruction. This will result in a NullReferenceException and not in an AccessViolationException since this AV did occur inside the managed environment. AccessViolationExceptions are thrown when the CLR does call into unmanaged code and an AV comes back from there.

Comment: @AloisKraus Ok, but that's just semantics right? The CPU raises a page fault, the OS takes the page fault, sees that no memory is mapped in that linear address, makes it an invalid page fault, which is thrown into the user mode code through the exception handling system. The runtime catches it and feeds it into the managed code as one of those two types. I didn't know before that it distinguished them like that but that facility doesn't provide much benefit. It's not like I'm going to handle managed AVs that shouldnt happen some special way everywhere.

Comment: In other words, I'm saying that you shouldn't be treating any access violation as a normal code path. The expense of a well placed 'if' is negligible compared to the 10k+ instructions for a page fault. You get the linear address when you get an AV, the cmp [ecx],ecx just makes the linear address always be zero in the exception in callvirt. When does you program look at the linear address and say, "oh okay, its at address zero. Carry on." It's a bad implementation if you rely on that.

Comment: There is a difference. When it does happen because you did call into a null object the CLR does exactly know that nothing did break. If you get an AV from external code it could have overwritten half of your memory. The first is a programming error in managed code which is recoverable. The second is not since you do not know what has happened.