# How can I simulate an access violation exception from my c# code?

Tags: c#, iis, access-violation

How can I simulate an access violation exception from my c# code? If I write the code "Throw new AccessViolationException", the program doesn't throw an unhandled exception and create an entry in the event viewer. (I've written the code as a WCF service and hosted in IIS)

My main objective is to create an access violation exception multiple times and want to simulate the scenario where the "rapid fail protection" setting of the IIS app pool is breached.

Comment: _" A System.AccessViolationException occurs when unmanaged/unsafe code attempts to use memory that has not been allocated, or to memory that it doesn’t have access to."_ - so no, you can't just throw one. To simulate it you could try `unsafe` or c++ - [source](https://airbrake.io/blog/dotnet-exception-handling/system-accessviolationexception)

Comment: `var ptr = new IntPtr(42);Marshal.StructureToPtr(42, ptr, true);` should do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to generate/produce a c0000005 Access Violation Exception in pure managed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386280/is-it-possible-to-generate-produce-a-c0000005-access-violation-exception-in-pure)